# Mapping through an array of dictionary and then passing values as props in the component

Tags: reactjs

This is my current code of the parent component:

```
return (
   <div>
     <SideBarField name={"Dashboard"} icon={"fa fa-th-large"}/>
     <SideBarField name={"My Calendar"} icon={"fa fa-calendar"}/>
   </div>
   )
```

And this is the child component:

```
 <li class="active">
     <a href="dashboard_2.html"><i className={`${props.icon}`}></i> 
        <span class="nav-label">{props.name}</span>
     </a>
 </li>
```

Now instead, I'll create an array of objects like this and then pass in that data using mapping.

```
 const fields = [
        {name: 'Dashboard', icon: 'fa fa-th-large'},
        {name: 'My Calendar', icon: 'fa fa-calendar'}
    ]
```

How do I write the map function for that where I'll pick up the name and icon for every iteration and pass on to this component

```
  <SideBarField name={data from array} icon={data from array}/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `.map()` function and pass the values inside the child component. `idx` is used because your `fields` array of object is not having any unique `ID` and while using a component inside `.map()`, the root component needs a `key`.

```
<div>
  {fields.map((field, idx) => (
    <SideBarField key={idx} name={field.name} icon={field.icon}/>
  ))}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
return (
   <div>
     {
   fields.map((field,i)=> <SideBarField key={`${field}-${i}`} name={field.name} icon={field.icon}/>)
}
   </div>
   )
```

in child component

```
 <li class="active">
     <a href="dashboard_2.html"><i className={`${props.icon}`}></i> 
        <span class="nav-label">{props.name}</span>
     </a>
 </li>
```