# how to render multiple instances based on array data React

Tags: reactjs, render

I have an array with objects including different coordinates such as:

```
bottomRow: 130.8201356
leftCol: 52.33386899
rightCol: 279.71340993
topRow: 48.9834268
```

what I need is to render squares based on this data. As many squares as there is different objects in the array.

I have tried this code with no success:

```
const FaceRecognition = ({imageUrl, box}) => {
     console.log('recog',box)
  return (
    <div className='item-e center ma'>
        <div className='absolute mt2 z-2'>
            <img className='image br4 ma4 z-2' id='inputImage' src={imageUrl} alt=''/>
                {   box.forEach(() => {
                    return (
                        <div className='bounding-box' style={{top: box.topRow, right: box.rightCol, bottom: box.bottomRow, left: box.leftCol}}>
                        </div>
                    )
            }
                
                )
            }
        </div>
    </div>
  );

}
```

how should I solve this so it takes all the objects and renders all the squares? So far I had to put [0] or any other array index next to `box` and it renders only that one object. but I need rendering all at once.

update:

I have tried `box.map` like this:

```
const FaceRecognition = ({imageUrl, box}) => {
     console.log('recog',box)
  return (
    <div className='item-e center ma'>
        <div className='absolute mt2 z-2'>
            <img className='image br4 ma4 z-2' id='inputImage' src={imageUrl} alt=''/>
                { box.map(((topRow, rightCol, leftCol, bottomRow), idx) => {
                        <div key={idx} className='bounding-box' style={{top: box.topRow, right: box.rightCol, bottom: box.bottomRow, left: box.leftCol}}>
                        </div>
                        }
                    )
                }
        </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

still no success, I get `Invalid parenthesized assignment pattern` now but can not figure out why

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mapping through an array of dictionary and then passing values as props in the component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66257994/mapping-through-an-array-of-dictionary-and-then-passing-values-as-props-in-the-c)

Comment: Why are you using `box.forEach()` instead of `box.map()`? Array.forEach will always return `undefined`, so its use case is more limited than map.

Comment: I am a beginner, still learning...will try .map

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you should be using map, since forEach will return undefined.
Second, you forgot to use the control variable inside map/forEach, you map sould be done like so:

```js
const FaceRecognition = ({imageUrl, box}) => {
     console.log('recog',box)
  return (
    <div className='item-e center ma'>
        <div className='absolute mt2 z-2'>
            <img className='image br4 ma4 z-2' id='inputImage' src={imageUrl} alt=''/>
                {   box.map((element) => {
                    return (
                        <div className='bounding-box' style={{top: element.topRow, right: element.rightCol, bottom: element.bottomRow, left: element.leftCol}}>
                        </div>
                    )
            }
                
                )
            }
        </div>
    </div>
  );

}
```

The box you are using there is the full array, so it´s  impossible to get this elements.

Comment: the same code that is shared before but well-explained :), upvoted for you

Answer (score 1):

You should try the map function and add an arg in the map function.

```
const FaceRecognition = ({ imageUrl, box }) => {
  return (
    <div className='item-e center ma'>
      <div className='absolute mt2 z-2'>
        <img className='image br4 ma4 z-2' id='inputImage' src={imageUrl} alt='' />
        {box.map((item) => {
          return (
            <div className='bounding-box' style={{ top: item.topRow, right: item.rightCol, bottom: item.bottomRow, left: item.leftCol }}>
            </div>
          )
        })
        }
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const FaceRecognition = ({imageUrl, box}) => {
    console.log('recog',box)
    return (
        <div className='item-e center ma'>
            <div className='absolute mt2 z-2'>
                <img className='image br4 ma4 z-2' id='inputImage' src={imageUrl} alt=''/>
                {box.map(({topRow, rightCol, leftCol, bottomRow}, idx) => (
                    <div
                       key={idx}
                       className='bounding-box'
                       style={{
                           top: topRow, 
                           right: rightCol, 
                           bottom: bottomRow, 
                           left: leftCol
                       }}>
                    </div>
                ))}
            </div>
        </div>
   );
}
```